# Cordova file transfer DOMString

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I am using Cordova file upload plugin with Ionic app and sending it to Laravel back-end. It uses JWT auth and when sending request I have to forward token along parameters.

```
var options = new FileUploadOptions();
options.chunkedMode = false;
options.fileName = 'someFileName.jpg';
options.params = {token: localStorage.getItem('token')}

var ft = new FileTransfer();
alert(JSON.stringify(options))
ft.upload('$scope.picData', encodeURI(SERVER + 'user/post'), win, fail, options);
```

Problem is (i presume) that in Cordova documentation it says that parameters are forwarded as DOMString because I get `400 error token_not_provided` on the Laravel side... any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You may need to check how your backend expects to be provided with the authentication token, but in most cases it is in the headers and not as parameters. Check the [upload method documentation](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-file-transfer/#upload) and especially the [second example](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-file-transfer/#example-with-upload-headers-and-progress-events-android-and-ios-only) -

(dummy code)

```
var options = new FileUploadOptions();
options.chunkedMode = false;
options.fileName = 'someFileName.jpg';
options.headers = {
    "token": localStorage.getItem('token')
};
```

Comment: I tried with token also. I am posting it as params with every other normal http request, but this one simply does not pass

Answer (score 0):

Change token and use "Authorization"

```
options.headers = {
"Authorization" : localStorage.getItem('token')
}
```

Here a example.

```
var options = {
  fileKey: 'file',
  filename: filename,
  chunkedMode: false,
  mimeType: 'multipart/form-data',
  params: {
    'filename': filename
  },
  headers: {
    'Authorization': $rootScope.token //returns a string like 'JWT AmG...'
  }
};
```